# Update Umbraco to the latest version on Azure App Service

Tags: azure, content-management-system, umbraco

A client of mine would like to use Umbraco.
Just because we always use Azure, we decided to use the [following ARM template](https://portal.azure.com/#create/umbracoorg.UmbracoCMS) (and, for example, not move on Umbraco Cloud).
My questions are:

- how the updates are managed?
- what appens if a major/minor is released? Is the CMSautomatically updated?
- In the following image, taken from the Umbraco App Service on Azure Portal, you can see there is the **Deployment Center**. What is it?
- When a new version of Umbraco is released, can I press the "**Sync**" button to update it to the last version?

thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with the sync button, it do a KuduSync.NET with the repo, the Web.config will be overwritten and some other files, Your Umbraco database connection string is lost and Umbraco comes in the install mode.

KuduSync.NET is a Tool for syncing files for deployment, will only copy changed files and delete files that doesn't exists in the destination but only if they were part of the previous deployment (manifest file).

So for example your upload media files will not be destroyed.

For upgrading see the [Umbraco Upgrades in general](https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/getting-started/setup/upgrading/general) first read if there are special instructions for your version. and make a backup!.

For the web.config file in the root of your site:

> **Important**: make sure to copy back the version number, and the connection string
>   as they were.

Than Umbraco knows how to upgrade. The installer will guide you through the upgrade. when your hit the site and the version number in the web.config is not equal. If your using SQL CE be really careful with the App_Data/Umbraco.sdf

So on a minor upgrade you can try it with the sync button. But it is not the official path. (first create a backup) and direct after sync, restore the version and connection string in the web.config.